# Relation of any set A

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I've been learning of relations and I'm having trouble on how to proceed with this problem:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \text{On any set } A: a\sim b \enspace\enspace\forall \enspace a,b \in A
> \end{align}
> $$

It's pretty obvious to see that $a\sim a$ as $(a,a) \in R \Rightarrow (a,a) \in R$, but how can this be shown true for symmetry and transitivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Symmetry*

It follows that $\enspace a \sim b \implies b \sim a \enspace\enspace\forall \enspace a,b \in A $, since anything implies something true: formally, $Q \implies (P \implies Q) $.

The same applies to transitivity.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\sim b$ holds for *all* elements $a,b\in A$, then the claims needed for symmetry/transitivity are trivially true.

Comment: How would I formally show this?